# Raspberry Pi and RetroPie distro plus LCD

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, tar, raspberry-pi3, lcd

I downloaded RetroPie for my RaspberryPi 3 from this [link](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/First-Installation/) and have been trying to get my 3.5" LCD to work. I downloaded the driver from [here](http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html) as described, but whenever I try and extract it with the "tar xzvf LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz", the file for the Osoyoo LCD I have, around 50 lines are executed and then the Pi crashes. When I restart it, it goes into a kernel panic every time. I've reinstalled my OS multiple times. I cannot download the raspbian distro with the driver because I have been unable to install RetroPie on top of it and have been unable to display it on the LCD.

Install [instructions](http://osoyoo.com/2016/09/13/install-raspberry-pi-3-5-touch-screen-driver-for-raspbian-jessie/) and [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013E0IJVE):

Please respond if you know how to solve this problem or what you recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not using enough power. The usb cable I used was a spare rather than official cable for the Pi. Not enough voltage to complete the tasks.